# Sending PDF attachment from form submission - script not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have used a script as suggested by LEARN GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS on youtube.  All functions are working except for the sendEmail function - it is driving me bonkers now....can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {

    const info = e.namedValues;  
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
    const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
    const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Responses");
  
    sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email address for your certificate'][0],pdfFile);

}


function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Your Heartstart Certificate", "Your certificate is attached.", {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Meon Valley Heartstart'
    });
  
}

function createPDF(info){

  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1sVhEpamhLvhlfxHg61zF9rptri5Momm3");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1v7VF7MTV_hB-9PeLIWRr5MdR4Fa3IrZF");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1dCv5B0zDqebm7ZRtT-qs7eWB_kLOKR8A-mKgeFdORv0");

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Name}", info['Your name as you want it to appear on your certificate'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Date}", info['Date you completed the course'][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Your name as you want it to appear on your certificate'][0] + " " + info['Date you completed the course'][0]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting this error each time:Exception: Invalid argument: attachments
sendEmail @ Code.gs:15

Comment: Doesn't `createPDF` return no value? The line `const pdfFile = createPDF(info)` is just going to return empty so you're passing null into `sendEmail()`

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to return the file from `createPDF`.*

#### Fix:

After the line:

```
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Your name as you want it to appear on your certificate'][0] + " " + info['Date you completed the course'][0]);
```

Add:

```
return pdfFile.getBlob()
```

Then change your email sending call:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Your Heartstart Certificate", "Your certificate is attached.", {
  attachments: [pdfFile.getBytes()],
  name: "Meon Valley Heartstart",
  mimeType: "application/pdf"
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much - almost there I'm hopinh.... but - I'm now getting a different error Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
afterFormSubmit @ Code.gs:3

Comment: Stackoverflow is a single problem - single solution Q&A site, if this solved your issue, please accept the answer that's been helpful to you as it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too, and then ask a new question with all the information for your new issue so people can take a look :)#

Comment: No it hasn't solved the problem - still no PDF sending as per the original question, but a different error is showing since changing the code